# Parse request sent by Volley to PHP

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I want to send a request to database using Volly in android. This is my request

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        postData(params[0]);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Code Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
        pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
        try {
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContexy);
            String URL = Config.Get_FeedBackURL;
            JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
            jsonBody.put("email", SharedPrefs.getString(mContexy, SharedPrefs.KEY_email," "));
            jsonBody.put("ID", "ir.gfpishro.mobile");
            jsonBody.put("Author", SharedPrefs.getString(mContexy, SharedPrefs.KEY_name," "));
            jsonBody.put("comment", valueIWantToSend);
            final String mRequestBody = jsonBody.toString();

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.i("VOLLEY", response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType() {
                    return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                }

                @Override
                public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                    try {
                        return mRequestBody == null ? null : mRequestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                        VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", mRequestBody, "utf-8");
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                    String responseString = "";
                    if (response != null) {
                        responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
                        responseString = String.valueOf(response.data);

                        // can get more details such as response.headers
                    }
                    return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
                }
            };

            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

It sends request into php webservice but I can not handle it,I used this code in my php file

```
 $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$objd = json_decode($_POST);

echo $objd["ID"];
//"ID", "ir.gfpishro.mobile"
     if ($objd["ID"]== "ir.gfpishro.mobile") {

        echo $obj["email"];
        echo $obj["Author"];
        echo $obj["comment"];

        //fetch product id from ibecon
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `userComments`(`useremail`, `username`, `text`) VALUES ('as','dd','dddd')");

        $stmt->execute(array($obj["email"],$obj["Author"],$obj["comment"]));

        sendResponse(200, json_encode($obj));         

        return true;

    }else if(isset($_GET["companyid"])){


        sendResponse(203, json_encode($result));          

        return false;

    }



}
```

Php return `PHP Warning:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in` and then return status code of 200.I want to know How can I handle posted data in php file. 
Thanks

Comment: `$_POST` is an array _per definition_, since it is one of the super global arrays PHP provides when being initialized as a module inside a http server environment. So you do _not_ have to decode it.

Comment: @arkascha thanks,But how can I get posted parameters and decode into json?

Comment: Just take a look into the `$_POST` array. That will answer your question. Dump the array into a log file or use a debugger or whatever. You then can directly access the elements contained in that array. And you certainly do _not_ want to "decode into json". It might be that _one of the elements_ inside that `$_POST` array is a json encoded string. Then you want to decode _that_ string. But you have to differ between the array `$_POST` and an element inside that array which you simply can access by its key like `$_POST['someKey']`.

Comment: @arkascha thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because json_decode accept a string as JSON , you're trying to convert all superglobal var wich is an array containing more information than just the data you're sending.
Try to do instead :
`$objd = json_decode($json,true);`

Notices the true arg meaning to cast array instead of stdObject.
Also you can var_dump($POST) and you will see how is the structure of it.